# Latest Post Feature from wordpress not displaying on site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe

I am struggling with the latest post feature. I want to have my latest posts from wordpress be displayed onto my index home page which has to remain in html format as far as I know. That being said I am trying multiple options on trying to get the feature to display. Currently I am working on an iframe option.

Here is the iframe displayed on the index.html:

```
<iframe src="headlines.php" name="blog" height="250px" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ><a href="http://www.hidesertheat.com/headlines.php" title="News"></a></iframe>
```

Here is the php code from the headlines.php:

```
<?php  
$how_many=2; //How many posts do you want to show
require_once("http://www.hidesertheat.com/news/wp-config.php"); // Change this for your path to wp-config.php file ?>
<?
$news=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_title FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_status= \"publish\" ORDER BY 'ID' DESC LIMIT ".$how_many);
foreach($news as $np){
printf ("
<li><a>%s</a></li>
", $np->ID,$np->post_title);
}?>
```

My wordpress blog is here: http://www.hidesertheat.com/news/ This is my first time using wordpress so I honestly do not know what exactly I am doing.

My main site is here: http://www.hidesertheat.com/

Please let me know if you know what is going wrong and if you have any suggestions.

Thank you so much!

Edit from the headlines.php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h1>Not Found</h1>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Currently I am not seeing an error. Nothing is being displayed. When I go to: http://www.hidesertheat.com/headlines.php it shows nothing yet I did upload it on the server.

Comment: Can you not use the normal WP Loop?

Comment: I thought I wasn't able to use the WP loop on a html site? This is my first time using wordpress

Comment: Use it on your headlines.php

Comment: Have you got PHP error reporting turned on? Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: I added the changes both of you stated but Im not seeing anything different?

Comment: You should really use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of custom SQL.